# xbbg pulling bdp data with multithreading

Tags: python, pyqt5, bloomberg

I am trying to develop a pyqt5 app where I can live stream stock prices from Bloomberg. I put some field names (eg. LAST_TRADE) in the ThreadClass (QThread) to pull price every second. I also have a function in the main class to pull some non-realtime data (eg. PX_YEST_CLOSE) from Bloomberg whenever a push button is clicked. I ran into this issue that when the push button clicked, it sometimes returns LAST_TRADE data instead of PX_YEST_CLOSE. I think this is because the API only allow one request at a time. Is there a better way to workaround it?

I've included a simple version of my code below just to illustrate. Thank you!

```
import sys, time
from xbbg import blp
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from ui_interface import Ui_MainWindow

ticker = ['AMD Equity', 'NVDA Equity', 'CHK Equity', 'ABNB Equity', 'AFRM Equity', 'U Equity']

live_fields = ['LAST_TRADE']

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """Class for the Main window"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.thread={}
        self.getStaticData()
        self.connectSignalsSlots()
        self.start_worker()
    
    def getStaticData(self):
        '''Pull static data from Bloomberg'''
        self.staticData = blp.bdp(list(set(ticker)), flds=['CUR_MKT_CAP', 'PX_YEST_CLOSE'])
        self.label_2.setText(str(self.staticData.iat[0,0]))

    def start_worker(self):
        self.thread[1] = ThreadClass(parent = None)
        self.thread[1].start()
        self.thread[1].any_signal.connect(self.liveFeed)

    def liveFeed(self,liveData):
        self.label.setText(str(liveData.iat[0,0]))

    def updateData(self):
        '''Update table if clicked'''
        print(blp.bdp(['AAPL Equity'], flds=['CUR_MKT_CAP', 'PX_YEST_CLOSE']))
    
    def connectSignalsSlots(self):
        '''Signal-slots connections'''
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.updateData)

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.is_running = True  
    def run(self):
        print('Starting...')
        while (True):
            data=blp.bdp(ticker, flds=live_fields)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.any_signal.emit(data) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    control = MainWindow()
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    widget.addWidget(control)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

UI below:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(590, 582)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(360, 80, 75, 23))
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(90, 70, 171, 41))
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(90, 140, 171, 41))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 590, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Update", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"TextLabel", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"TextLabel", None))
```

Comment: Your code isn't streaming live data ... not in the sense that `xbbg` or Bloomberg understand it. What you are doing is polling Bloomberg every 100ms for the latest value. Maybe check out the example code here (https://pypi.org/project/xbbg/) for `blp.live` ... and "subscriptions". The principle is that you "subscribe" to a live data stream, which will fire an event in your code when a new datapoint arrives.

Comment: Thanks @DS_London! And you are right, I am not streaming live data, should have been more clear. BBG has daily limit of ~500K request, unless with BBG server API, this cap will be hit really soon given the number of names I am monitoring.

Comment: @DS_London Sorry to bug you, but do you know if xbbg can stay in connection with Bloomberg if I convert this python code into exe standalone file / 1 directory? For some reason it's giving me connection error once converted. Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid I have never tried this.